# Below is the code to return leap year by passing argument

Tags: python

```
def leap(year):
    return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)
```

I am new to python. I am writing a program that should take a year as input and return a Boolean whether the year is a leap year or not. Above is the code of my professor which I am trying to understand but I am not sure why my professor is using (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)

Comment: Century years are only leap years if they are divisible by 400. e.g., 2000 was a leap year but 1900 was not

Answer (score 0):

`%` is a modulo operator in Python.
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html
`% 100` is being used to check if the `year` is divisible by 100 or not. This is because `200` is also divisible by 4 but it's not a leap year. For a leap year, you require `4` and `100` to be multiples. However, `% 400` is not required.